# In the Mac Finder, if I use the search box, how can change the focus back to the located items via keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

I've been a power user of both Windows and Mac for decades, but this seemingly simple thing has me stumped!

If I use the search box, how do I change the focus to the located items, using the keyboard?

One would think hitting Tab a few times would do the trick, but Tab seems to do nothing useful in this scenario.

Comment: Are you talking about the spotlight search in the menu bar or the search box in a finder window?

Comment: The search box in a Finder window

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? I can reproduce in Lion, but I think this was different in earlier versions.

Comment: I can confirm that Tab works in Snow Leopard (10.6.8)

Comment: @tidbeck Really? `tab` just takes me seemingly nowhere.

Comment: @slhck Try hitting `tab` two times or `tab` and `down arrow`.

Comment: @DanielBeck What's it like in Lion? what can you "reproduce"? The fact that it's not working anymore?

Comment: Using Lion. Interesting. I think I can test on Snow Leopard later today. Yeah, when you hit tab, focus seems to move to the search scope bar, but it's grayed out and you can't go anywhere from there.

Comment: @Jeff Exactly what I see on Snow Leopard. Shift Tab would work, but that's a bit of a PITA

Answer (score 0):

**OS X 10.6:**

If you go to *System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts*, make sure to disable "All controls"

[image]

Now, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after searching, and it will take you to the results list. I guess this is a bug, as you can't tab through to the list when enabling "All controls". It just gets stuck on "This Mac".

A workaround, if you have "All controls" enabled all the time, would be to tab back five times.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on Lion though.

Comment: @Lri That's why I said 10.6 :) — Can't test it. Did they break it completely?